# Deleting Project from Workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I am attempting to delete an Android project from my Eclipse workspace. However, when I try to delete it, I run into an error: `Problems encountered while deleting resources - org.eclipse.core.resources`. Examining the error gives me: `Could not delete 'filepath'. - org.eclipse.core.resources` as well as an `Internal Error - org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring`.

Here's the error logs

`Could not delete 'filepath'.`

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered while deleting files.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.delete(LocalFile.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1937)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

`Internal Error`

```
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 273] Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: Could not delete 'C:\Users\jli\workspace\Android Workshop\res\layout\main_image.xml'.
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered while deleting files.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.delete(LocalFile.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1937)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\jli\workspace\Android Workshop\res\layout\main_image.xml.
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: Could not delete 'C:\Users\jli\workspace\Android Workshop\res\layout\main_image.xml'.
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered while deleting files.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.delete(LocalFile.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1937)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.access$0(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange$1.run(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: I added the Android tag because the project I'm deleting is an Android project and I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. I'll delete it if necessary.

Comment: restart your machine after that don't run anything. Just open eclipse and delete the project.

Comment: That worked. If you write an answer up I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your machine after that don't run anything. Just open eclipse and delete the project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the files from that project opened currently. close them all in the active window and then try deleting.

Comment: I had already closed all windows before attempting to delete.

Comment: Do you have any image opened? Close the image file....clean your workspace and try again.

Comment: I tried cleaning it and I actually got a new set of errors. `Failed to load properties file for project 'Android Workshop'`.

Comment: Hmmm..try going to  the location and deleting them physically. go to the workspace in your C:/ drive and delete them. Make sure you close eclipse and then delete all the files you want. This will definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do a File/Refresh on the project first. Eclipse caches the folder/file structure and does not re-read it until told so.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a program that is being used by the application therefor u can not be run cleaning.i suggest u try to close all running applications, close the Eclipse and  end task adb.exe in task manager and then run eclipse again and then do cleaning again.